How do I find $|A|$ in this context?


$100$ people were randomly selected and asked the following question: Which of these three stores do you visit weekly (at least once per week), Store A, Store B, or Store C? The following results were obtained: $10$ visit Store A and Store C, $37$ visit Store B but not Store C, $20$ visit Stores B and C, and $28$ visit none of the three stores.

I am trying to figure out how many people exclusively went to store A. My first strategy was to find every value except for A, but I was unable to find a value for B since the numbers do not add up properly.
Is there a strategy I am not seeing? If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciated. (Please don't give me the answer)

10 + 37 + 20 + 28 is 95, not 100, at a bare minimum you have the wrong numbers.

This is all the info I have

Are the numbers in the diagram given to you by the problem, and not derived by you? i.e. are they additional information?

They are in the given problem, yes

Anecdote my post doesn't touch on: you do not seek $|A|$, but instead $|A \setminus (B \cup C)|$, since you are seeking those exclusively going to Store A. Be mindful of this difference in working future problems!

Ooooh ok, I think I see the mistake

Note: After confirming with OP, the numbers in both the diagram and stated in the text of the question are given pieces of information, although the presentation is a little weird (probably a fault of the source material). There ends up being a well-defined answer with, to my knowledge, no contradictions, so the problem is not flawed, just poorly presented.

Visualizing Each Number:
You were told

$10$ people visited $A$ and $C$, i.e. $|A \cap C|=10$. This corresponds to this region in the diagram:



$37$ visited $B$ but not $C$. This corresponds to this region in the diagram:



$20$ visited $B$ and $C$, i.e. $|B \cap C|=20$. This corresponds to this region in the diagram:



$28$ visited none of the stores, which corresponds to this region in the diagram:


The diagram gave to you three more pieces of information:

The number of people visiting $A,B$ but not $C$ is $30$, and that's these people:



The number of people visiting all $3$ is $10$:



The number of people visiting $C$ exclusively is $11$:



Sum Total of Knowledge:
Cumulatively, then, we know these regions' sizes:

(NOTE: Dashed lines are meant to erase the boundaries between regions, but keep them vaguely visible, so some of the numbers above will be giving their values to multiple regions if a dashed line allows their color to "bleed over"!)

Moving Forward:
Clearly, the second and third diagram above give us all of $B$. So with that and a few other regions, we know:

We really just need to find this region to finish it out:

Two particular diagrams will help:

This means that

$10$ people visited $A$ and $C$, and maybe $B$ or maybe not
$10$ visited all three
So clearly, no person visited $A$ and $C$ but not $B$, i.e. the missing number is $0$:



Conclusion:
Now with this information, and the fact that $100$ people are represented overall, we can find the remaining region by summing up the numbers in the colored diagram above and subtracting from $100$.
$$
100 - \Big( 37+20+0+11+28 \Big) = 100 - 96 = \color{green}{\boxed{ 4}}
$$
giving us the diagram

Having completed the remainder of the diagram, in the sense of narrowing down the number of people for each particular region, I can confirm that the diagram ends up being consistent with the given information stated in text and in the given diagram, though its presentation is odd enough to be confusing.

That is a long-winded but colourful way of solving $8$ equations in $8$ unknowns.

I tend to find that students struggle with this, especially if they're not math students themselves, so I'd rather break it down slowly and take my time and explain myself, than speed along to a solution.

This is essentially solving $8$ equations - three in your Venn diagram and five in the words - in $8$ unknowns.  You end up with $$100 - 30 - (37-30) -(10-10) -10 -(20-10) - 11 -28= 4$$
illustrated by this annotation of your initial Venn diagram (effectively condensing PrincessEev's diagrams into one).

